# QRD450(android 9) google play service crash

Tags: java, crash, google-play-services

In my devices of QRD450(Android 9) ,i install google play services,google play store ,google serviceFrameworks,google accounts.but when i open the play store,the system show the play serivces begin crash message.I've tried many versions of play services,but it's not work.

the detail crash message is :

```
addOnPermissionsChangeListener: Neither user 10100 nor current process has android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS.
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5944)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:201)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1657)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
DeviceDoctorHandler: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: addOnPermissionsChangeListener: Neither user 10100 nor current process has android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS.
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.addOnPermissionsChangeListener(IPackageManager.java:6356)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.addOnPermissionsChangeListener(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1484)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at rdw.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090033@15.0.90 (100300-231259764):12)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@15090033@15.0.90 (100300-231259764):89)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
DeviceDoctorHandler:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5939)


AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime: PID: 6616
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: Component com.google.android.gms/.chimera.container.SharedModuleProvider requests FLAG_SINGLE_USER, but app does not hold android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.attachApplication(IActivityManager.java:3959)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.attach(ActivityThread.java:6570)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.isSingleton(ActivityManagerService.java:20606)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.generateApplicationProvidersLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11952)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7749)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8025)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:198)
AndroidRuntime: 
am_crash: [6616,0,com.google.android.gms,-1597489596,java.lang.SecurityException,Remote stack trace:
am_crash:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.isSingleton(ActivityManagerService.java:20606)
am_crash:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.generateApplicationProvidersLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11952)
am_crash:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:7749)
am_crash:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8025)
am_crash:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:198)
am_crash: ,Parcel.java,1950]
ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.google.android.gms u0
```

Comment: Still not solve this issue?